# Identity Server 4 - How can I apply an ApiScope in a real world use case?

Tags: scope, identityserver4

I am new guy with Identity Server 4. ApiScope concept is unclear, could you please explain it more detail? And how can we apply it in real.

Example: Web API will have below modules, I want to restrict access to module, can I based on it? If it is possible, how can we configure it in system

```
Scopes =
    {
         new Scope()
         {
             Name = "accountmanagement",
             DisplayName = "Account management api",
         },
         new Scope()
         {
             Name = "stockmanagement",
             DisplayName = "Account management api",
         }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you're asking.  Do you want to restrict modules access for a whole client - meaning, the whole application cannot consume Stock management for instace **OR** you want to restrict it per user, meaning user A will be able to access account management, user B will be able to access stock management, user C won't be able to access both, etc...

Comment: Original, I want to restrict it per user. But With below answer, scope is only for client. Thanks.

Comment: Ok then - if you want to restrict access per user I posted an answer that describes how to achieve that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scopes are an abstract concept that you can use how you see fit to subdivide (or not) your API resources. For example, you might have:

- One scope that covers multiple physically different APIs ("OurEnterpriseScope")
- One scope per physical API ("OurDataAccessApiScope", "OurFinanceApiScope")
- Multiple scopes per physical API, at whatever granularity you see fit. Maybe two: one for read and one for write. Maybe one for normal users and one for admin users. Maybe a scope for every single endpoint (but don't ...)

In IdentityServer you specify which scopes your client(s) have access to, using `AllowedScopes` on the `Client` object. So you might have a client that can only use the 'MyApiUser' scope and a different client that can use both the 'MyApiUser' scope and the 'MyApiAdmin' scope.

Scopes are *not* a function of the `user`, only the `client` the user is using.

It is entirely up to you how you want to break up your resources.

In your API you need to define the `AllowedScopes` within your `UseIdentityServerAuthentication`, so that your API knows which scopes it will accept within an access token. If you have an API that accepts multiple scopes and you want to control access to your endpoints based on what scope the access token has (because your API supports multiple clients, each with different scopes) then you can define `Policies` based on `Claims` (the scope is just wrapped up as a claim).

A good read can be found here: https://leastprivilege.com/2015/12/28/validating-scopes-in-asp-net-4-and-5/

Comment: Thank you! The part "the scope is just wrapped up as a claim" is something which I didn't understand and that changed everything!

Answer (score 3):

After understanding you want to be able to restrict access to modules based to certain users, not for the whole applications - that can achieved by user-claims (most common implementation is the `role` claim).

You can save a role for each user - either `AccountManager` or `StockManager` (or both).
Then, define a new `ApiResource` with at least one `Scope`, that scope will contain `UserClaims` - the claims in which you want to manage the user check upon.

```
new ApiResource
{
    Name = "rolesResource",
    DisplayName = "Roles",
    Scopes = {
        new Scope
        {
            Name = "roles",
            DisplayName = "User Roles",
            Description = "A list of all the roles assigned to the user",
            Required = true,
            UserClaims =
            {
                JwtClaimTypes.Role
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then - your client could ask that specific `roles` scope

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "your_client_id",
    // More configuration...
     AllowedScopes = {
        // Whatever scopes needed and...
        "roles"
    }
},
```

Then when your client asks for an access token it has the relevant roles and your controllers / actions can use the `AuthorizationAttribute` to make sure that each user has the desired access-level.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AccountManager")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "StockManager")]
    public IActionResult OnlyAccessibleForBothAccountManagerAndStockManager { }
}
```